# how can I fix this bug : 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I'm trying to write a function to calculate the GPA of a student but I have this bug `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'` . I want to put `AVGPA` inside `if sid in student.SID` so that I could link the GPA to its student.

Could anyone help me with this one ? Thank you

```
stumarks = []
class student: 
  def __init__(self,id,name,DOB):
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.DOB = DOB
    student.avgGPA = None
class marks_object:
  def __init__(self,CID, SID,SN, m,crd):
    self.CID = CID
    self.SID = SID
    self.SN = SN
    self.m = m
    self.crd = crd
def MarkInput(): 
 CourseID = input("Enter the course's ID : ")
 credit = crd_of_course()
 if CourseID not in [CourseInfo.id for CourseInfo in courselist]:
       print(" The course's id isn't founded! Please try again!")
 else:
  nm = int(input("Number of student that you want to enter marks: "))
  for i in range(nm):
    while True: 
      StuID = input("Enter a student's ID : ")
      SN = input("Enter the student's name : ")
      if StuID not in [StudentInfo.id for StudentInfo in studentlist]:
        print("The student's ID isn't founded! Please try again! ")
        continue
      if SN not in [StudentInfo.name for StudentInfo in studentlist]:
        print("The student's name isn't founded! Please try again! ")
        continue
      break
    marks = RoundDown()
    obj = marks_object(CourseID,StuID,SN,marks,credit)
    stumarks.append(obj)
def avgGPA():
  sid = input("Enter the student's ID : ") 
  coursecredit = []
  coursemark = []
  for student in stumarks:
    if sid in student.SID:
      coursecredit.append(student.crd) # I HAVE THE BUG IN THIS LINE
      coursemark.append(student.m)
      coursecredit = np.array(coursecredit)
      coursemark = np.array(coursemark)
      output = np.sum(np.multiply(coursecredit,coursemark)) 
      sumcrd = np.sum(coursecredit)
      AVGPA= output/sumcrd
      student.avgGPA = round(AVGPA,1)
  print(f"The student's GPA is {round(AVGPA,1)}")
```

Comment: numpy arrays don't have a method append. that's why you cannot append them.

Comment: The syntax is wrong, its `numpy.append(array, values)`, Reference: [numpy.append](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)

Comment: also why are you declaring `student.avgGPA = None` instead of `self.avgGPA = None`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki  I think it's because I could update the GPA for a student.

Comment: yes, that's why you should use `self.` inside the `__init__` function. why do you think doing `student.avgGPA` will work?

Comment: In one loop, `coursecredit` starts as `[]`.  But after one list append you assign `np.array(...)`.  An array does not have an append method.  Stick with lists!

Answer (score 0):

`append` method works when `coursecredit` is `[]`, a list.  It fails when it is an array in the next iteration.

```
  coursecredit = []
  coursemark = []
  for student in stumarks:
    if sid in student.SID:
      coursecredit.append(student.crd) # I HAVE THE BUG IN THIS LINE
      coursemark.append(student.m)
      coursecredit = np.array(coursecredit)
```

Why did you think this would work?  The error should have sent you searching `numpy` for an `append` method, and reviewing basic Python for list append.  There is a `numpy.append` **function**, but its usage is different, and behavior different as well.  Stay away from it.

At least you noted where the error occurred, though it's easy to miss.  Showing the full error message would have been better.